# what does this line of code do w.r.t. sticky header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-head

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What's the use of this line "in sticky header example"  ? I have seen this in a sticky header example.

***source-code link*** : http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/how-to-create-an-animated-sticky-header-with-css3-and-jquery/download.zip

***website link*** - http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/how-to-create-an-animated-sticky-header-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to refer the Libraries in your project.

1. Pointing to local copy
2. Pointing to hosted Libraries. [ Faster and easy comparing to local copy]